# Is there a way to check when a firebase function last ran?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I inherited  project and I'm trying to sanitise the functions. I have 50 functions I'm wondering what's the best way to see when the functions were last run? From the firebase project console (functions tab) I can get logs for the different functions. Some functions have no logs. Can I assume if a function has no logs that it never ran?

Comment: What are the function triggers or is it scheduled or something ?

Comment: mainly http endpoints

Comment: Do you get response from those functions back when the logs are not visible?

Comment: haven't tried, can try now... but would of thought there would of been some logging..

Comment: It should log any invocations if enabled. But you can still the timestamp of last execution in a database and keep updating it after every invocation.

Comment: Cloud Functions include simple runtime logging by default. Logs written to stdout or stderr will appear automatically in the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&_ga=2.89772441.367954762.1627298996-1727701255.1626769955&_gac=1.190057945.1626949979.CjwKCAjwruSHBhAtEiwA_qCppscOEAEs2ziMdzbH7XBWLr0LoRh0_T_7Rq-cYDWvy0OR3rTJ7ZKVMxoCn1UQAvD_BwE). For more advanced logging, use the [Cloud Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_logging_api).